# Knowrob_gui installation

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to Knowrob. I would like to install also the semantic map editor, and I followed the guide.

Once I do rosmake knowrob_gui, I get many errors, like this:

```
      /home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/src/edu/tum/cs/ias/knowrob/map/SemanticMapEditorForms.java:589: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : method getName()
  location: class controlP5.ControlEvent
            if(theControlEvent.getName().equals("rot_y")) {
                              ^
  /home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/src/edu/tum/cs/ias/knowrob/map/SemanticMapEditorForms.java:590: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : class ObjectInstance
  location: class edu.tum.cs.ias.knowrob.map.SemanticMapEditorForms
                ObjectInstance cur = ((ObjectInstance) OWLThing.getOWLThingByShortname(t_id.getText())); 
                ^
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/build'
  [ 99%] Built target _java_compile_1_12
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/build'
  [ 99%] Built target _java_compile_1_13
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/build'
  [ 99%] Built target _java_compile_1_14
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/build'
  [ 99%] Built target _java_compile_1_15
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/build'
  [ 99%] Built target _java_compile_1_16
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/build'
  100 errors
  [ 99%] Built target _java_compile_1_17
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/build'
  make[3]: *** [../bin/edu/tum/cs/ias/knowrob/map/SemanticMapEditorForms.class] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_java_compile_1_53.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  [ 99%] Built target _java_compile_1_18
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/lwr/Development/ros_workspace/ros/knowrob_gui/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package knowrob_gui written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/lwr/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140206-104442/knowrob_gui/build_output.log                                                                           
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< knowrob_gui [FAIL] [ 20.28 seconds ]                                                                                                                                                                                
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package knowrob_gui. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                                                                                                               
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[ rosmake ] Built 30 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                                                                                                               
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[ rosmake ] /home/lwr/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140206-104442
```

Can someone help me? Any suggestion is welcome!
Maybe @moritz can help me :)

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126701/knowrob_gui-installation/) by [Noah](https://answers.ros.org/users/8581/noah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hmm, do you use an up-to-date knowrob from github? The binaries are quite outdated and somewhat broken.

You'll need the 'complete' version from here if you want to use the GUI.
http://www.knowrob.org/installation#installation_from_source

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2014-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Noah](https://answers.ros.org/users/8581/noah/) on 2014-02-07**:
Hi @moritz, you're right. I installed the .deb version. Now with source installation seems working.